# Additional fields from lookup column not showing in mail notification

Tags: sharepoint-online, lookup-column, email-notification

I setup a list with a lookup column and some additional fields from the linked list.

Everything works good in the SharePoint web site (additional fields show correctly) but the notification mail I receive when I create/modify a new record doesn't show the additional fields.

For example, this is the SourceList:
[image]

and this is the DestinationList, that includes a Lookup column (OrderName) and the 2 additional fields (OrderName and OrderDate) from SourceList:

[image]

The problem is that the notification mail (in the example below, it's been received after Title3 has been added) includes only the lookup column (OrderName) and not the 2 additional fields (OrderName and OrderDate):

[image]

Is there any way to have ALL the fields included in the mail?

Comment: How you setup these notification emails? Using "Alert me" OR "List Rules" OR Power automate flows?

Comment: I used alert me

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is normal. When we go to the edit form, it will not show you the additional field as we could not edit the additional field, this is by design.

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.

Comment: I'm not sure I wrote the question correctly (or maybe I misunderstood the answer): I don't need to edit the additional fields when in edit mode... I just wondering why the notification mail doesn't include the additional fields which are instead displayed in the list on sharepoint online.

Answer (score 0):

When I get a notification through sharepoint rule, the mail is like this:
[image]

If I click "go to item", I will get the edit form:

[image]

Normally, additionanl field will not display in this form.

---

If the answer is helpful, please click "√" on the left panel of the answer and kindly upvote it.